# Multiple statements in one macro

Tags: c, macros

Is it correct way to write a multiple statements in one Macro?

```
 #define AB() do { printf("hi"); } while(0)
```

Comment: A macro is just text replacement. I don't think the question makes sense. You don't generally have something *in* a macro because a macro is not a syntactic unit.

Comment: Now that depends on how you want to use the macro

Comment: The macro in question has the advantage that the use can be written as a function call, i.e. `AB();`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Although the correct way is most often to not have any function-like macro at all.

Please note that the do-while(0) trick is only relevant in code bases with sloppy brace style, such as

```
if(x)
  AB();
else
```

The do-while(0) trick will prevent compiler errors caused by the stray semi-colon, if there is an `else` statement following. Had the macro only used braces, you'd get `if(){}; else` which is a syntax error.

Note that the above brace style caused one of the most expensive software bugs in history, known as the Apple "goto-fail" bug. So there are very sound reasons never to use it. If you always use `{}` after every statement, the do-while(0) trick also turns irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the correct way.

Ideally you want a macro to expand into a *single* statement, *not* a *compound* statement. Yours satisfies that.

You can safely use this macro in an `if`, `else` block.